# Ruby on Rails fails on bundle install when using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have not much knowledge of Ruby. I have to host a Ruby website. When I make deploy setup and check, is everything ok. But when I cap deploy I get the following error.

```
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/lpavisit/releases/20131009211837; true"
    servers: ["x.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [5.56.61.183] executing command
    command finished in 209ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/lpavisit/releases/20131009211837 && bundle install --without development test'" on x.xx.xx.xxx
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add the entire error message. You clipped off the part describing why it failed.

Comment: See the terminal message first its removing the directory  executing "rm -rf /var/www/lpavisit/releases/20131009211837; true Then try to enter same directory using cd command. cd /var/www/lpavisit/releases/20131009211837  && bundle install --without development test'" on x.xx.xx.xxx. I think something might be wrong your deploy script.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a Capistrano-based deploy system is a bit complex. You might want to give [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) a try until you're more familiar with Ruby. But to continue with Capistrano, first ask it if it has everything it needs to deploy:

```
$ cap deploy:check
```

You want to see it say, *You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed*. Yours probably won't. In that case, you should look for a good capistrano book or online tutorial.